# Add to Cart in custom block Homepage Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, addtocart, home-page

I am trying to add a **Add to cart** button in a custom block being added to the homepage.

I've looked at many SO / MSE posts and all refer to Object Manager but I know it's not meant to be used, and from the look of what's been said I can see it being removed a few versions down the line, or at least changed in a way where all the code being suggested will break.

The closest thing I've found to get a working button is:

```
<?php $collection     = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper'); ?>
<?php $postData       = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($prod), ['product' => $prod->getEntityId()]) ?>
```

but it returns a JS error in console:

```
TypeError: params.data is undefined 
    params.data.form_key = formKey;
```

This makes me think, It expects few things to be in a form?
So I guess my real question is, what is the Magento 2 equivalent of

```
<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Using Widget***

We can add the listing product on Homepage by using Widget.
**CONTENT > Pages >** Choose home page cms > **Content > Insert Widget**. We can choose **Widget Type: Catalog Products List**

[image]

If we want the Widget product to use Ajax, we need to create a form submit for each product. Remember to add form key for it.

*app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/default/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml*

```
.....
<?php
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()]);
$postParams = json_decode($postData, true);
?>
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
......
```

Adding Javascript:

```
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form]": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

**See more here: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

If we want to create a custom listing product block with Ajax add to cart, we can follow the same logic.

Comment: does this mean you have to add a widget per product? Creating a widget makes me fill out the product that it links too, this sorta implies having to do a lot of widgets?

Comment: No, we need to add only one widget- product listing widget. Because,  by default, doesn't use Ajax, we need to override the default widget template.

Comment: So what product do I link it to? It's a required field for me?

Comment: `It's a required field for me? `? Which is required part?

Comment: Under Widget Options > Product

Comment: `Widget Options > Number of Products to Display`? You can give me the link of your widget screen shot?

Comment: no worries - realised where I went wrong, misread the option in your select box, I selected product not products :S

Comment: Oddly enough still get that params.data error - I have a feeling there's some JS I'm missing, insepcting the element looks like the button has the correct data now (thanks) but maybe missing one small thing?

Comment: Is there any Js custom? Clear your Magento Cache and Browser Cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48169/discussion-between-123tfo-and-khoa-truongdinh).